# Почему данные из первого поля в форме не пересылаются?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Столкнулся не очевидной вещью, данные из первого поля в форме не пересылаются по ajax. Не могу понять в чем причина.

Вот как выглядит форма

```
         <form id="clientAddBody">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Имя</label>
                    <input name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Фамилия</label>
                    <input name="SecondName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Отчество(Не обязательно)</label>
                    <input name="MiddleName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Отчество(Не обязательно)">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Вот так выглядит Ajax

```
   $('#submit').click(function (e) {

        var premisesViewModel = $('form').serialize();

        console.log(premisesViewModel);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Client/SaveClient',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data:  JSON.stringify(premisesViewModel),
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                ClientLoadToCard(data);
            }

        });


    });
```

В итоге я получаю данные по всем полям, кроме `FirstName` не могу понять , почему так происходит. Меняю местами поля, к примеру SecondName ставлю вперед и соответственно null оказывается там.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а чего вы не используете стандартные механизмы ajax-форм? какой смысл делать это вручную?

Comment: и уберите этот `stringify`  с `dataType: json`, ибо у вас там сериализуется get-строка с параметрами формы, а не нормальный объект.

Comment: а что в premisesViewModel в консоли?

Comment: @EVG Там все ок. Показываются все данные